# How to select from a table and divide the values with the result of another query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Consider I have this table:

```
create table currency(
currency            char(3)                 
                    PRIMARY KEY,

rate                decimal,                

buy                 decimal,                 

sell                decimal                 


);
```

and I have this data:

```
insert into currency(currency,rate,buy,sell) values('EUR', 1, 1, 1);
insert into currency(currency,rate,buy,sell) values('USD',  0.8979, 0.901, 0.887);
insert into currency(currency,rate,buy,sell) values('GBP', 1.12404, 1.14405, 1.10543);
```

now I want to select the rates based on USD exchange rate then I want the rate, buy, and sell columns of all rows to be divided by the USD rate. i.e

I want something like

```
select currency, rate/<usd exchange rate>, buy/<usd exchange rate>, sell/<usd exchange rate>  from currency;
```

the  can be selected like:

```
select rate from currency where currency='USD';
```

Comment: what's `u_money` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun sorry fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch from the table twice in just one query:

```
SELECT c.currency, c.rate / u.rate AS rate, c.buy / u.rate AS buy, c.sell / u.rate AS sell 
FROM currency c, currency u 
WHERE u.currency='USD';
```

Will do a cross join between the complete table and the row for US-Dollar.

Comment: ... or with JOIN syntax: `SELECT ... FROM currency c JOIN currency u ON u.currency = 'USD';` But Postgres will show the same query plan for both.

Comment: indeed - no need here